# Is XLA Compiler enabled by default in tf 2.2

Tags: python, tensorflow, xla

My system has `Tensorflow 2.2 (Python 3.8, anaconda)`. I read about the Tensorflow XLA Compiler and to my understanding it is an alternative way to precompiled GPU operations that Tensorflow ships with. Even when I run code without eager execution or `experimental_compile=True` I see `XLA service 0x5644b1cec990 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used)` in the terminal.
Also if it is linked in some way, the `Executing op Fill in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0` takes considerably long time (~2mins) before proceeding to the next op.

Answer (score -1):

As far as the release notes go: Yes, XLA now builds with windows and is shipped with all prebuild packages

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases

Comment: it is included yes. But is it the default compiler / executor framework now, even when not enabled explicitly?